Significance of Convergence Theorems in Analysis
We use theorems like Monotone Convergence, Dominated Convergence, Bounded Convergence theorems to show that when a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ in a measure space $X$ converges to some function $f$ in $X$ almost everywhere that we can assert the corresponding claim
$$\int_X f_n \,\, d\mu\to \int_X f \,\, d\mu$$
I'm wondering what the fundamental error in the following line of reason is: Suppose $f_n \to f$ a.e. in $X$. Then $a.e.$, $|f_n - f| \to 0$. Then by the triangle inequality
$$\left| \int_X f_n \,\, d\mu - \int_X f \,\, d\mu \right| =\left| \int_X f_n - f\,\, d\mu \right| \leq \int_X |f_n-f| \, \, d\mu \tag{1}$$
And so now as $|f_n-f|$ can be made arbitrarily small, one would think that we could make the final integral vanish and hence make the LHS go to $0$. What are the various situations that flaw this line of reasoning? One that comes to mind is if for some fixed $x$, the sequence of outputs $f_n(x)$ grows very quickly toward some ill-defined $f(x)$; this idea is vaguely reminiscent of the Dirac delta function. Could an example be provided that uses the format $(1)$?

$|f_n-f|$ can't be made arbitrarily small. For a simple counter-example, take $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$, the characteristic function of the interval $[n,n+1]$. Then $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x$, so $f$ is identically zero; but $\sup |f_n-f|=1$ for all $n$, and $\int|f_n-f|d\mu=1$ for all $n$.

don't you mean $\int |f_n - f| d \mu = 1$? this read confusingly to me first of all

Thanks @GeorgeC, you are right of course.

If you add up $n$ copies of $1/n$, each copy goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ but the sum doesn't. This can be viewed as a failure of the tightness hypothesis in the Vitali convergence theorem.
If you look at the area of the rectangle $[0,1/n] \times [0,n]$, the part of it outside of any strip $[0,a] \times \mathbb{R}$ goes to zero, but the whole area is still $1$ all the time. This can be viewed as a failure of the uniform integrability hypothesis in the Vitali convergence theorem.
The Vitali convergence theorem tells you that these are the only ways for convergence to fail besides $f_n$ failing to converge to some $f$ even in measure.
